# How to agglomerate rows/lines in Python Pandas, based on one reference column?

Tags: python, pandas, row, cell

Let's say we have a DataFrame like this in Pandas:

```
         0                                1                     2          3               4
0     Date                      Description                              ABC             DEF
1                                                     LOREM ISPUM                    1234.00
2    01/08          LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM                            12.34                    
3                      ABCDEF ABCDEF ACBDEF                                                      
4    01/08                   DOLOR SIT AMET                            56.78                    
5               CONSECTETUR ADIPISCING ELIT                                                              
6                     SED DO EIUSMOD TEMPOR                                                              
7    07/08                      LOREM ISPUM                            90.12
8    08/08                   DOLOR SIT AMET                                            34.56
```

Rows can take 1 line (#7 or #8), but can also be multiline: for example for lines #2-3, or #4-5-6, you can see that the column `1 / Description` is split on several lines.

**How to merge rows such that they all take one line, based on a reference column (here `0 / Date` ), with Pandas?**

Expected output:

```
         0                                                                  1                     2          3               4
0     Date                                                        Description                              ABC             DEF
1                                                                                       LOREM ISPUM                    1234.00
2    01/08                       LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM ABCDEF ABCDEF ACBDEF                            12.34                    
3    01/08   DOLOR SIT AMET CONSECTETUR ADIPISCING ELIT SED DO EIUSMOD TEMPOR                            56.78                                                                                  
4    07/08                                                        LOREM ISPUM                            90.12
5    08/08                                                     DOLOR SIT AMET                                            34.56
```

Note: if, after the header "Date, Description, , ABC, DEF", a row has an empty Date, don't agglomerate until one non-empty date comes: here line #1 is not agglomerated.

Comment: Move the first row to the header  as columns would be a  good first step to clean up  the data :)

Answer (score 1):

For the date rows i.e. rows from 2 to end (`df.iloc[2:]`) do `ffill` on '0' column and `groupby` and `agg` using `' '.join`, but because some dates may repeat, use a `cumcount` of the groups to identify each group and use both columns '0' and 'column obtained from cumcount' as grouper.

Then concat the aggregated frame to the first two rows `df.iloc[:2]`

Code:

```
df_date_rows = df.iloc[2:].copy()
df_date_rows["0"] = df_date_rows["0"].astype(str).str.strip()
df_date_rows["date_count"] = (
    df_date_rows.loc[~df_date_rows["0"].str.match(r"\s+|^$")]
    .groupby("0")
    .cumcount()
    .ffill()
)
df_date_rows["0"] = (
    df_date_rows["0"].str.replace(r"\s+|^$", lambda x: np.nan, regex=True).ffill()
)
out = (
    pd.concat(
        [
            df.iloc[:2],
            df_date_rows.groupby(["0", "date_count"], as_index=False).agg(" ".join),
        ]
    )
    .reset_index(drop=True)
    .drop("date_count", axis=1)
)
```

print(out):

```
       0                                                  1            2  \
0   Date                                        Description                
1                                                            LOREM ISPUM   
2  01/08       LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM ABCDEF ABCDEF ACBDEF                
3  01/08  DOLOR SIT AMET CONSECTETUR ADIPISCING ELIT SED...                
4  07/08                                        LOREM ISPUM                
5  08/08                                     DOLOR SIT AMET                

         3        4  
0      ABC      DEF  
1           1234.00  
2   12.34            
3  56.78             
4    90.12           
5             34.56
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use the groupby and agg functions as below:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'date':['2022-01-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-04'],
        'description':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
        'value1':range(1,6),
        'value2':range(1,11,2)}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

df2 = df.groupby('date').agg(
    description_agg=pd.NamedAgg(column='description', aggfunc=lambda x: x.str.cat(sep=', ')),
    value1_agg=pd.NamedAgg(column='value1', aggfunc='sum'),
    value2_agg=pd.NamedAgg(column='value2', aggfunc='mean')
)
```

There are some ways to aggregate data as you can see on the documentation (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html). I use this way because you can control the result column name and function applied on each column.

Comment: Thanks but I don't think this works in this example. In my example some rows have an empty "date" column, and this is precisely the rows which should be grouped with the previous ones. Also, multiple rows might have the same date and should not be grouped (see updated question).

Comment: Here @GregoryOliveira an example would be `data = {'date':['2022-01-01', '', '2022-01-02', '', '2022-01-02'], ...}`, that should give an output with 3 rows of date '2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-02'.

Comment: @Basj, I will return later on this question. I just finishing my shift at work now. After some rest, I will deal with your (and now my too) problem! :-)